# Commercial version of Simba JDBC driver

Tags: google-bigquery, simba

We are using Simba JDBC driver for connecting to BigQuery using Japsersoft reporting solution. Expecting 100 or 1000 of reports running at the same time. Due to huge number of connections to BQ, does this impact the reports performance/limits number of connections allowed as JDBC driver is free downloadable. Is there a commercial version of the Simba JDBC driver available?